# switching frequency vs size of the passive elements

Tags: power, inverter, mosfet-driver

why increasing the switching frequency reduces size of the passive elements in DC to 3 phase AC inverter?

Comment: Are you talking about the output filtering that uses inductors and capacitors?

Answer (score 1):

Energy gets stored in those elements. At 100X higher frequency, the stored energy drops 100 fold, and the "size" (uF, uH) can drop 100 fold.